# Amazon S3 connection reset randomly

Tags: javascript, http, file-upload

I' am uploading files to Amazon S3 using multipart part from JavaScript. The problem I' am facing is that requests fail randomly with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error or similar error. Sometimes a request get failed even after 18 seconds and sometimes it completes transmitting data to Amazon. I' am completely out of guess that what could be the cause of this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @JeffRyan This issue occurred randomly and without any particular reason. I simply fixed this issue by resubmitting that ajax request if  it failed :-).

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. From what I see, Amazon resets requests with weird `Referer` URLs. Not sure what the exact conditions are though.